# SOQL Queries in Salesforce

Tags: soql

I have to query all the accounts where more than 1 contact with the field (primary = true). 
Let say, I have an Account and it has 3 contacts, 2 of contacts having a field(primary = true). So I have to fetch there 2 contacts only with Account. If I have 3 Contacts and 1 contact of them having a field(primary =true) this contact I don't want to get. Please let me know the SOQL query for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to approach this kind of query - locating parent objects by count and attribute of their children - is often an aggregate query. The skeleton would look something like this:

```
SELECT count(Id), AccountId
FROM Contact
WHERE Primary = true
GROUP BY AccountId
HAVING count(Id) > 1
```

You can execute this query in the developer console, or assign it to a `List<AggregateResult>` in Apex and loop over those records to process them.

For more, see [Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.214.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm) and [Working with SOQL Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm).

Comment: Thanks, David for this really It helps. Can we get Id of Contact also ? becoz by this I am not getting the contact Id.

Comment: No, you cannot do that in an aggregate query. You must use aggregated data (`count()` etc) and grouped fields only, in your `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Can't we add any other fields? I want to add AccountId, name , country etc..Is this possible?

Comment: Rahul, the query in my answer includes `AccountId`. You cannot include non-grouped or -aggregated fields in an aggregate query. You would need to accumulate the Ids in a Set and perform a second Account query to get these details.